# Too few arguments - wp_login action

Tags: php, plugin-development, actions

I'm looking for a way to avid that some custom users roles are able to see wp-admin dashboard. I've found [this topic](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/401823/redirection-of-users-away-from-wp-admin-but-not-administrators) and in my plugin class I've tried to use the two action suggested, but I will get an error about too few arguments passed.

This is my implementation of the code

```php
    public function hide_dashboard_from_users( $user_login, $user )
    {
        if( !current_user_can('manage_options') && is_array($user->roles) && in_array('customer', $user->roles) ){
            wp_safe_redirect( site_url('/user-profile') );
        }elseif( !current_user_can('manage_options') && is_array($user->roles) && in_array('operator', $user->roles) ){
            wp_safe_redirect( site_url('/customers-manager') );
        }
    }
```

into the class construct I have these two actions

```php
        add_action('wp_login', array($this, 'hide_dashboard_from_users'), 10, 2);
        add_action('admin_init', array($this, 'hide_dashboard_from_users'));
```

Why I will get the error and how I can fix it? Is there other actions or filter I can use to achive this?

Answer (score 1):

The custom role needs the *read* capability to view the backend.

Example:

```
$your_role = get_role('your_custom_role');
$your_role->add_cap( 'read' );
```

See: https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/roles-and-capabilities/#read

Ideally, this should only be done once, e.g. when activating your plugin or theme.

Comment: Not sure to understand, The custom role already have the read permission when the plugin is activated, what I need is to avoid that this role can see the wp-admin dashboard, why I will need to set the read capability twice?

Answer (score 0):

I've finally found a solution. I've used the `admin_init` action to redirect users that will have certain custom roles to the pages that they will need to see.

In a method of the plugin now I've this code

```php
    public function hide_dashboard_from_users()
    {   
        $user = wp_get_current_user();

        if( !current_user_can('manage_options') && is_array($user->roles) && in_array('customer', $user->roles ) ){
            wp_safe_redirect( site_url('/user-profile') );
        }elseif( !current_user_can('manage_options') && is_array($user->roles) && in_array('operator', $user->roles) ){
            wp_safe_redirect( site_url('/customers-manager') );
        }
    }
```

And into the plugin class construct I've added this

```php
add_action('admin_init', array($this, 'hide_dashboard_from_users'));
```

After some tests seems working fine.